# Scraper not returning any values with jquery using cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Trying to scrape the front page of a website ([www.ozbargain.com](http://ozbargain.com.au)) to return any content in the a tag that holds a reference to xbox but nothing is being returned to console. I believe the issue is with the if statement with :contains.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio');

url = 'http://www.ozbargain.com.au';

request(url, function(error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    if($("a:contains('Xbox')").length) {
      //console.log(this);
      var el = $(this);
      var log = el.text();
      console.log(log);
    } else {
      console.log('hey');
    }
  }
});
```

The html block I'm after. In particulare, I want the a tag;

```
<h2 class="title" id="title214252"><a href="/node/214252">Free on Xbox One, Xbox 360, PS3, PS4: Tales from the Borderlands (Episode 1)</a></h2>
```

Comment: Your selector must be wrong. Open the console in your browser and see if that selects the item you're expecting.

Comment: Here is the full string of html. How would I concatenate this to form my selector? `<h2 class="title" id="title214252"><a href="/node/214252">Free on Xbox One, Xbox 360, PS3, PS4: Tales from the Borderlands (Episode 1)</a></h2>`

Answer (score 1):

Assigned the selector to a variable then called the text method.

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var $el = $("a:contains('Xbox')");

        if ($el.length) {
            console.log($el.text());
        } else {
            console.log('hey');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cheerio syntax for contains is slightly different than jQuery. Ommit the single quotes around the string you're searching for an it should work:

```
$("a:contains(Xbox)")
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Consider the following code: `console.log(cheerio.load("<p>hello world</p>")("p:contains('hello')").text());`. This prints `hello world` regardless of whether there are quotes around `'hello'` or not.